# Run SIP demo Android platform 2.3 on AVD's

Tags: android, testing, sip, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

Android 2.3 platform contains a SIP demo project. I want to test this project on two AVD's, not on real Android devices. I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You can run SipDemo at Android Emulator if you use this IMG - http://xilard.hu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Testing SIP Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html#testing)

> Testing SIP Applications
>
> To test SIP applications, you need the following:
>
> - A mobile device that is running Android 2.3 or higher. SIP runs over wireless, so you must test on an actual device. Testing on AVD won't work.
> - A SIP account. There are many different SIP providers that offer SIP accounts.
> - If you are placing a call, it must also be to a valid SIP account.
>
> To test a SIP application:
>
> 1. On your device, connect to wireless (Settings > Wireless & networks > Wi-Fi > Wi-Fi settings)
> 2. Set up your mobile device for testing, as described in Developing on a Device.
> 3. Run your application on your mobile device, as described in Developing on a Device.
> 4. If you are using Eclipse, you can view the application log output in Eclipse using LogCat (Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat).

So it looks like you have to use a physical device to test SIP applications.

Comment: Guys, university is providing me two mobile sets but they can support 2.1 version for android support. is that possible to upgrade the sets to android platform 2.3, so that i can use SIP API provided by androids?

Comment: @Zahir: That depends on what device you are using. You should ask that on http://android.stackexchange.com