# Android SIP demo

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem to run SIP demo Android platform 2.3 on AVD's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388367/problem-to-run-sip-demo-android-platform-2-3-on-avds)

I am new to android and I want to develop a android based simple SIP application which can make and receive a call.
For that purpose first I have tried to experiment on SIP Demo Application provided by Android.
Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html) from which I have downloaded that application resources.

Environment and Resource i am using is as below:

- Android 4.0.3
- sdk Api level 15.
- asterisk  1.8.7.1
- OS : Fedora 15
- IDE : Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1

I have tried to run on 4.0.3 API 15 but the line `manager = SipManager.newInstance      (this);` is always returning null value.

Also I tried to run on android 2.3(API level 9) and android 3.1(API level 12), but still it gives me value of manager as null.

I have given all the permission correctly in my applications android manifest as   well,but when i try to run on emulator Voip and SIP will results false and manager as null.

I have also try to run on mobile Samsung Galaxy Y (Android 2.3.6) but on that also  manager result as null.

Its not even giving any error and no registration request is coming in asterisk  console as well.

Note: I have configured SIP users and Contexts in my asterisk conf files correctly, I  tried registering and making call from softphone and its working perfect, but when I am   trying to call through Android SIP demo then there is no action in asterisk.

Can anyone please give me some solution like what configuration or setting or platform I am missing to run this application successfully?

Is it possible to run this SIP demo on emulator? If not then Which device is required to run this demo successfully?

Comment: You can run SipDemo at Android Emulator if you use this **[IMG](http://xilard.hu/)**, because by default **SipSettings** are not activated in emulator.

Comment: now i can run this demo in emulator but how to run on phone?Because for that there is any img file which i can put in mobile.so how to run in phone this demo.